# AJAX post in using slim framework outputs 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim

I have been stuck on this for days now, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765711/run-slim-post-route-from-ajax-query) is my previous question, but none of the comments seem to work. I have tried multiple things and managed to get rid of the 404 error, but now there is a 500 error...

- Basically I want to post an AJAX query when an event happens.
- Run a Slim post route using the AJAX query parsing through a value.
- Select data from the database using the Slim post route using the parsed through value.
- Then return the results from the query and display them in a selection box.

If anyone has any idea how to solve this I would be so grateful!!!

Here is the code:

```
//Post the AJAX request
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select#add-module-stackid').change(function() {
            var val = document.getElementById("add-module-stackid");
            var val2 = val.options[val.selectedIndex].value;
            //alert(val2);
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/admin-get-add-module',
                data:{stackid:val2},
                dataType:'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.error(JSON.stringify(response));
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.error("error");
                    alert('Not working!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the Slim Post Route code:

```
$app->post('/admin-get-add-module', function () use($app){
$req = $app->request();
$myStacks = filterStacks($app);
$app->view()->appendData(array('data' => $data, "stacks"=> $myStacks, "username" => getUsername($app)));
$sql = $link->prepare("select * from evironments where StackID=?");
$sql->bind_param("i", $stackid);
})->name('admin-get-add-module');
```

It doesn't seem to run the route

Image to show console error:

[image]

Here is the header error:

[image]

Comment: You're not telling it what to select from the table.  Try `select * ...`

Comment: Oops, just added that in... still doesn't work :/

Comment: Consider checking your server logs in order to identify what's exactly the error is. (Or just set `debug = true` in your framework)

Comment: What is the 500 error telling you in the console

Comment: I have put a screen shot of the error

Comment: You need to debug the server error - it's not a problem with the client, unless you're sending bad data, but you still need to debug the server to find out.

Comment: I have added an image of the header error, how do I debug the server error?

Comment: ohh I see thank you, says undefined variable `exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: data'` I will have another play to try and find a solution, cheers for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the 500 internet server error. I wasn't parsing through the link.

```
$app->post('/admin-get-add-module', function () use($app,$link){ <<<<<<<<LINK HERE
    $req = $app->request();
    $stackid = $_POST['stackid'];
    $myStacks = filterStacks($app);
    $app->view()->appendData(array("username" => getUsername($app)));
    $sql = $link->prepare("select * from evironments where StackID=?");
    error_log(var_export($sql,true));
    $sql->bind_param("i", $stackid);
})->name('admin-get-add-module');
```

It still doesn't work though [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845350/sql-query-returns-non-object-using-ajax-jquery-and-slim-framework) is a link to the sql / ajax problem